# How can I change the column name of an existing Class in the Parse.com Web Browser interface?

Tags: parse-platform

I couldn't find a way to change a column name, for a column I just created, either the browser interface or via an API call. It looks like [all object-related API calls](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects) manipulate instances, not the class definition itself?

Anyone know if this is possible, without having to delete and re-create the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this Parse forum answer : https://www.parse.com/questions/how-can-i-rename-a-column

> Columns cannot be renamed. This is to avoid breaking an existing app.
>   If your app is still under development, you can just query for all the
>   objects in your class and copy the value of the old column to the new
>   column. The REST API is very useful for this. You may them drop the
>   old column in the Data Browser

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it in python:

```
import json,httplib,urllib

connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
params = urllib.urlencode({"limit":1000})
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/Object?%s' % params, '', {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": "yourID",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "yourKey"
})

result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
objects = result['results']

for object in objects:
    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect()
    objectId = object['objectId']
    objectData = object['data']
    connection.request('PUT', ('/1/classes/Object/%s' % objectId), json.dumps({
         "clonedData": objectData
     }), {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": "yourID",
        "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "yourKEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    })
```

This is not optimized - you can batch 50 of the processes together at once, but since I'm just running it once I didn't do that. Also since there is a 1000 query limit from parse, you will need to do run the load multiple times with a skip parameter like

```
params = urllib.urlencode({"limit":1000, "skip":1000})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's not a feature provided by Parse (yet). But there are some third party API management tools that you can use to rename the fields in the response. One free tool is called [apibond.com](http://apibond.com)

It's a work around, but I hope it helps